# how can I upgrade virtualenv?

Tags: virtualenv

I installed virtualenv with bootstrapper. [here in github](https://github.com/lyk2014-python/bootstrap)

When I run `virtualenv --version` it shows 1.11.4. But I want to upgrade it to version 1.11.6. I use Linux Mint 17

Answer (score 0):

> sudo pip install virtualenv --upgrade